# Why does the data type change from int to float when exporting layers?

Tags: qgis

When I export Shapefile layers to Mapinfo format or Shapefile format integer values are automatically converted into float. Is there anything I can do to avoid this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried exporting as a .csv file (open it up with a spreadsheet program to see if the values have not changed) and then re-import it as a **Delimited Text Layer** in QGIS?

Comment: I am working on large number of data and export as .csv and again importing as a delimilated layer is quite time consuming task. also excel have certain limitations if it is more than 1 million record etc.

Comment: I tried with your suggesstion but its not working sorry

Comment: What about using `toint("Lat")`?

Comment: I dnt know about this function can you please explain?

Comment: In the attribute table, you can create a new integer column and in the expression filter, add `toint("Lat")` to copy all values from the Lat column and it converts them into integer values. I do not know if this works as it is meant to convert string data.

Comment: ok thanks i will try this and let you know quickly

Comment: It showing the same result. so in this case its not applicable.

Comment: Apologies buddy! Hopefully others will be able to advise.

Comment: Its ok..may be its issue with qgis tools . because i used arcgis and mapinfo for converting same shapefile. in both tools i got the result in integer format. dont know whats wrong with qgis.

again thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can't be reproduced. Please provide sample data which shows the problem in case you want this reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the tool is being too helpful.  Some tools scan for words like 'lat', 'x', 'lon' and 'y' kinds of strings in the column names.  Then the tool will make sure to keep the values in EPSG:4623 and make sure that you have a float data type.  Rename the column lat to something like my_a and column lon to something like my_b: x -> a; y -> b.  See if the export won't bother you at that point.  If this works, then you'd have to rename the exported column in a separate step.